# Using AVAudioPlayer to play remote mp3 file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift, but I want to change my view controller to play  a remote mp3 file in my iOS app. I started with this code to play a song locally, and it works (with functions for the player after):

```
import AVFoundation

class Music1ViewController: UIViewController {

    //5 -
    var songPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    //15 -
    var hasBeenPaused = false

    //6 -
    func prepareSongAndSession() {

        do {
            //7 - Insert the song from our Bundle into our AVAudioPlayer
            songPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "localsong", ofType: "mp3")!))
            //8 - Prepare the song to be played
            songPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

After looking at the `AVAudioPlayer` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer), `.prepareToPlay()` preloads the buffer, which makes me think all I need to do is change the initializer to target a URL.

Then I change the initializer:

```
songPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3")!)
```

I don't get any errors in XCode, but when I run it, I see an error in the console for `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)` which makes me think I am approaching this wrong.

Is there a better way to access the remote mp3 file?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563329/how-to-play-mp3-audio-from-url-in-ios-swift

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code :

You need to add `AVKit` & `AVFoundation` to your `frameworks` path and import them :

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player = AVPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func localPress(_ sender: Any) { 
        let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!+"/sound.mp3"
        print(path)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.play()
    }// i have created a btn for playing a local file, this is it's action


    @IBAction func urlPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://yourURL.mp3")!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.play()
    }// i have created another btn for playing a URL file, this is it's action

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me! I used the URL file (#2) for the project, and the audio is playing.

Comment: The question is about `AVAudioPlayer` and not `AVPlayer`

Answer (score 5):

My approach

```
func preparePlayer() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://yourURL.mp3") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        do {
            let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            let soundData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: soundData)
            audioPlayer.volume = 1
            let minuteString = String(format: "%02d", (Int(audioPlayer.duration) / 60))
            let secondString = String(format: "%02d", (Int(audioPlayer.duration) % 60))
            print("TOTAL TIMER: \(minuteString):\(secondString)")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: let soundData = try Data(contentsOf: url) /// it is a line of code that is often unused and causes an error and no sound.